# Choose child folder as root web directory in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, angularjs, visual-studio, web, iis-express

I have an angular project that has all info stored in a public/ folder inside VS. I want IIS Express to use the public/ as the root instead of the / as the root.  This is causing path issues within the index.html file.  Is there a way to do this?

The root is currently

```
http://localhost:15819/public/index.html
```

but I want it to be

`http://localhost:15819/index.htm`l

But keep the current project the same.

Answer (score 0):

when setting up the application in IIS, set the physical path to 'public/' in basic settings

Comment: This is IIS Express alot different.